# How to use with fixed footer positioning in WP7 ·

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

How to fixed footer in WP7 with Jquery-mobile

```
 <div data-role="footer"  data-position="fixed">
                    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
```

[image: Windows phone Footer]

Answer (score 1):

WP7 doesn't support position:fixed so toolbars should just scroll with the page unless you choose to include the optional polyfill, this is a fix:

https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Mobile-FixedToolbar-Legacy-Polyfill

Comment: I have This Error:"Object doesn't support property or method 'fixedToolbar'"  `$(".ui-footer-fixed").fixedToolbar("updatePosition");`

Comment: And that is because WP7 doesn't support position:fixed. Have you tried a fix?

Comment: Wait have you included js and css file from attached link? This error occurs where function fixedToolbar can not be found.

Comment: Load the into your HTML HEAD after jQuery Mobile has been loaded.

Comment: this is my HEAD `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/them.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css" />      
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.fixedToolbar.polyfill.css" />       
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />      
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>     
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.mobile.fixedToolbar.polyfill.js"></script>`